# What are good examples of mapping YAML data to Ruby objects?

Tags: ruby, yaml

I am looking for basic examples of YAML syntax and how to work with it in Ruby.
Basically, by looking at the examples, I hope to better understand how to map YAML scalars to object attributes, and whether to use different YAML files or having one YAML file containing multiple objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [YAML](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/YAML.html) class in Ruby core which has a short tutorial and a few links.

[YAML in Five Minutes](http://yaml.kwiki.org/?YamlInFiveMinutes)

[Serializing and Deserializing objects with Ruby](http://www.skorks.com/2010/04/serializing-and-deserializing-objects-with-ruby/)

```
require "yaml"

test_obj = ["dogs", "cats", "badgers"]

yaml_obj = YAML::dump( test_obj )
                    # -> ---
                         - dogs
                         - cats
                         - badgers
ruby_obj = YAML::load( yaml_obj )
                    # => ["dogs", "cats", "badgers"]
ruby_obj == test_obj
                    # => true
```

Comment: I have seen this. But if I want the data from the YAML file into e.g. a class Zoo. Is there a way to map dogs, cats onto a attribute pretty_animals ?

Comment: thanks, the 2nd reference gives the overview i was looking for. BTW reference kwiki seems to be out-of-service (?)

Comment: @poseid - Oh sorry about that, I thought it was just my work blocking that site